# Almacenar Datos de un archivo txt y guardar en una base de datos con VB

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Bueno le comento que estoy realizando extraer los datos de un archivo txt y almacenarlo en una tabla para ellos estoy usando las herramientas de :

- Sql server
- Visual Basic Window Form

Dentro de mi tabla solo tiene estos campos:

- Id int identity(1,1) not null
- numerocredito [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL

dentro de mi codigo este :

```
  Dim objReader As New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
        Dim sLine As String = ""
        Dim arrText As New ArrayList()

        Do
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            If Not sLine Is Nothing Then

                arrText.Add(sLine)
            End If
        Loop Until sLine Is Nothing

        objReader.Close()
        Using Con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conexion").ConnectionString)
            Con.Open()
            Using command As New SqlCommand("RegistrarDatosTxt", Con)

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opt", 1)

                For Each sLine In arrText
                    command.Parameters.Add("@numerocredito", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = sLine

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MessageBox.Show("Se Generaron Correctamente los Numero de Creditos", "..::Aviso del Sistema::..")
                Next
                Dim frm As New Form2
                frm.Show()

            End Using
        End Using
```

Le comento que si guarda informacion de un archivo txt pero solo si tiene un linea, pero si tiene mas de dos linea como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se registra y me indica el error que tiene mas campos establecidos. Mi pregunta es como pudiera guardar varios lineas de txt en mi tabla ?

Comment: @ctm002  disculpa pero no me esta almacenando todo los registro en la base de datos solo me esta almacenando el ultimo registro que hay en archivo txt yo quiero todo lo que esta adentro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea un comando por cada linea leída y ejecuta. Tal como lo hice aquí.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola ctm002. Gracias por la respuesta. Solo a modo de recordatorio, tanto en las preguntas como las respuestas, es preferible incluir código como texto en vez de imagenes. Eso facilita que alguien pueda conseguir la información por búsqueda en el web y también facilita copiar el código. Gracias.

Comment: Ok. Voy a tratar de dominar el tema del editor de respuesta. Soy nuevo en este tema.